# Code hanging inside a For loop

Tags: list-manipulation, infinite-loop

I'm pretty new to *Mathematica* (and functional programming in general). I'm working on some code to find winners (maximal values) in a list. The code I have that is hanging is this line.

```
For[i = 1, 1 <= Length[WinnerList] + 1, i++,  
  If[WinnerList[[i]] == winner, AppendTo[WinnerIndexList, i],]]
```

Basically, my code goes through a list, and adds the index `i` from that list to a second list, if the i-th entry is a 'winner'. My code hangs, but I get the correct output if I abort my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Then You should try to identify the infinite loop condition which makes Your code to run forever...

Comment: God I'm blind. Thank you much!

Answer (score 4):

Using `Position`:

```
Position[WinnerList, winner] // Flatten
```

Comment: We both had the same idea, but I think it is better to flatten the results for the OPs purposes.

Comment: @m_goldberg I did flatten. Just in postfix. Aka, the lazy man method.

Comment: So you did. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

As you probably realize by now, your code loops indefinitely because `1 <= Length[WinnerList] + 1` is always true. Now, let's look a better, functional way to solve your problem.

Making some data and getting the count of how many items in the list have the maximum value.

```
SeedRandom[42]; scores = RandomInteger[99, 1000];
Count[scores, Max @ scores]
```

> ```
> 11
> ```

Finding the indices where the maximum value occurs.

```
indices = Flatten @ Position[scores, Max @ winners]
```

> ```
> {52, 101, 161, 180, 428, 432, 437, 526, 546, 653, 779}
> ```

Checking the results.

```
Length @ indices
```

> ```
> 11
> ```

```
And @@ With[{max = Max[winners]}, scores[[#]] == max & /@ indices]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

A more functional approach:

```
Join[ WinnerIndexList, Pick[ Range@Length@WinnerList, WinnerList, winner ] ]
```